# Change Class Name in React state

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React JS, So basically I am working on a personal project just to test my react skill but I have this problem of changing the value of an object in state

```
   const [inputAll, setInputAll] = useState([])
   const [input, setInput] = useState([])
   const addList = () => {
        const newListItem = [{id: input.length + 1, value: 'go home', className: 'drop-list'}];
        setInputAll([...inputAll, ...newListItem]);
   }
   const changeClass = (Task) => {
        const newClass = 'drop-list delete';
        setInputAll((prev) => Object.assign(prev, prev.className: newClass))
        console.log(inputAll)
   }

   return (
       {input.map(input => {
         return (
             <div className="todo-row">
                <span className="todo-value">{input.value}</span>
                <span>
                 <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={addList}>Add</button>
                 <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={changeList(inputAll)}>Change</button>
               </span>
             </div>
          )}
       )}
     )
```

The result I get from the console when the "change button" is clicked is an array that contains 16 words

```
[{
0: "d"
1: "r"
2: "o"
3: "p"
4: "-"
5: "l"
6: "i"
7: "s"
8: "t"
9: " "
10: "d"
11: "e"
12: "l"
13: "e"
14: "t"
15: "e"}]
```

meanwhile what I want to get is `[{id: 1, value: 'go home', className: 'drop-list delete'}]`

Comment: Can you create a sandbox where you can show what exactly is the problem? You can use codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `inputAll` is a List of Objects, meaning there is no key for a list item but there is an index, you should know the `id` field or any other identifier and search for that object in the list in order for you to be able update the class name.

```
const changeClass = (id) => {
   inputAll.forEach((item) => {
       if(item.id === id){
           item.className = newClass;
        }
    }
    setInputAll([...inputAll])
}
```

OR

```
const changeClass = (index) => {
    inputAll[index].className = newClass;
    setInputAll([...inputAll]);
}
```